# How to display .9.png format of a picture in flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Here is my code:

```
new Image.asset('images/launcher/border_highlight.9.png', fit: BoxFit.fill)));
```

When I change the width and height of the image, it has a poor display effect, but show normal in native android.

Does flutter not support .9 picture? Is there another way to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 9):

Flutter supports similar concepts, but not directly support 9-patch files, so it actually works with any images.

For example, I have a 50x50 image here, `button.png`:

[image: image to be used as a button]

When zoomed in to 1200% in Photoshop, we can see the area which we would like to define as "center" so it can be stretched. I've drawn some blue guide lines at 15px from each edge:

[image: enlarged image]

To use it in Flutter, we can use the `centerSlice` property and pass in a Rect that basically defines the rectangle that I drew in Photoshop, i.e. spanning from 15px to 35px on both width and height:

```
        Image.asset(
          "images/button.png",
          height: 100,
          width: 350,
          centerSlice: Rect.fromLTRB(15, 15, 35, 35),
        )
```

And the result is as follows (vs not passing in `centerSlice`, but pass in `fit: BoxFit.fill` instead):

[image: demo]

Answer (score 3):

You can set the [centerSlice](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Image/centerSlice.html) property on the Image widget if you know the coordinates of the middle section of your nine-patch image. We don't currently read those coordinates out of the image automatically. If there's any documentation on how Android does that it's something we could consider doing, please don't hesitate to file a feature request.

Comment: It looks like the coordinates are simply black lines on the edges: https://radleymarx.com/ux/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Answer (score 0):

Currently Flutter supports

JPEG, PNG, GIF, Animated GIF, WebP, Animated WebP, BMP, and WBMP

See also https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/e7a294770012800fc8a43494fe646659b496ea49/lib/ui/painting.dart#L21

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Android nine-patch（.9.png）is a special png format, see [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch). What is the alternative way in flutter?

Comment: Sorry, don't know about that.

Comment: I guess you could manually split the images and use different scaling parameters for them, but that is not as nice as a nine-patch of course.