# Only stretch the center of the image in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, nine-patch, flutter-image

This is my image:

[image]

It's height is 8, but it's width is unknown, maybe 50, 100 or 200.

**What I want is the image's left and right side are not stretched when it's width changed.**

I use `centerSlice` but I don't clear it's value:

```dart
final bottomImage = Image.asset(
  ImageTool.findVariant(R.calendarMenuBottom),
  height: 8,
  fit: BoxFit.fill,

  //centerSlice: Rect.fromLTRB(10, 4, 10, 4),
);
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Check this answer for an explanation on how the centerSlice property works 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63254849/948942