# is it Posible Create This UI in FLUTTER?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

[image: I want make Container like this in Flutter for my Application, is is posbile through some tweaks in boxdecoration without using any packages?]

I want make Container like this in Flutter for my Application, is is posbile through some tweaks in boxdecoration without using any packages?
The sides of this view should be like that, something like a paper torn from a book.

Comment: Have you seen: [How to display .9.png format of a picture in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48056304/295004)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`CustomClipper`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomClipper-class.html) for this.

```dart
class CuponClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();

    path
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, 0);

    final radius = size.height * .065;

    Path holePath = Path();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
      holePath.addOval(
        Rect.fromCircle(
          center: Offset(0, (size.height * .2) * i),
          radius: radius,
        ),
      );
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
      holePath.addOval(
        Rect.fromCircle(
          center: Offset(size.width, (size.height * .2) * i),
          radius: radius,
        ),
      );
    }

    return Path.combine(PathOperation.difference, path, holePath);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

And use

```dart
body: Center(
  child: ClipPath(
    clipper: CuponClipper(),
    child: Container(
      height: 100,
      width: 400,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: Text("sdsdsd"),
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image]

Comment: for custom shapes there is a better solution: a custom `ShapeBorder` that allows borders, shadows, shape morphing, changing with  `MaterialState`s, using with `Material` / `Card` widgets etc - see existing shapes like: `BeveledRectangleBorder` / `CircleBorder` / `ContinuousRectangleBorder` / `MaterialStateOutlinedBorder` / `RoundedRectangleBorder` / `StadiumBorder` - those classes are all custom `ShapeBorder`s, not `CustomClipper`s

Comment: I will give a try on it

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library: https://pub.dev/packages/coupon_uikit

If you want to create own widget you must search **CustomClippers**. For example you can take a look this code:

https://github.com/lohanidamodar/flutter_custom_clippers/blob/master/lib/src/movie_ticket_both_side_clipper.dart